# How to avoid Mongodb from creating "members" fields in Json?

Tags: json, mongodb, spring-boot

I am storing Json Schemas/Objects in a mongodb to query them from a REST client. For accessing the database, I use Spring Boot with MongoTemplates. My problem is that mongodb seems to create several fields like "members", "_class" and "_id" automatically. I was already able to remove the _class and _id fields in the output, but these members seem to be quite persistent, I found no information about how to remove them (or suppress them in the output at least). I also can't just remove them from the objects after querying them because then all the information (title, definitions...) is gone, too.

Anyone out there who had this problem as well and can help? I would appreciate :)

Regards

Object(s) after querying out of mongodb:

```html
[
  {
    "members": {
      "__ID__": {
        "value": "c89bae58-8911-45a4-80b0-843278ac72c8"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "members": {
      "title": {
        "value": "LogicalNodes"
      },
      "__ID__": {
        "value": "a09ffc24-d25f-467a-bcd7-9eaed5fbc44e"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "members": {
      "title": {
        "value": "LogicalNodes"
      },
      "definitions": {
        "members": {
          "mv": {
            "members": {
              "type": {
                "value": "object"
              },
              "properties": {
                "members": {
                  "i": {
                    "members": {
                      "type": {
                        "value": "number"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }are
        }
      },
      "__ID__": {
        "value": "eb054bd3-2c50-43eb-9ee9-4c8e54a8236d"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "members": {
      "title": {
        "value": "TestObject"
      },
      "definitions": {
        "members": {
          "ab": {
            "members": {
              "type": {
                "value": "object"
              },
              "properties": {
                "members": {
                  "q": {
                    "members": {
                      "type": {
                        "value": "number"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "__ID__": {
        "value": "4b5a5813-5596-4c88-9a24-e19ae08b7548"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "members": {
      "$schema": {
        "value": "schema"
      },
      "title": {
        "value": "TestObject"
      },
      "definitions": {
        "members": {
          "ab": {
            "members": {
              "type": {
                "value": "object"
              },
              "properties": {
                "members": {
                  "q": {
                    "members": {
                      "type": {
                        "value": "number"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "__ID__": {
        "value": "e2a82f73-709d-410d-a79c-1e997f9fc5a4"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "members": {
      "$schema": {
        "value": "schema"
      },
      "title": {
        "value": "TestObject"
      },
      "name": {
        "value": "test"
      },
      "__ID__": {
        "value": "26089639-8b99-4f47-8696-d8f3e50694b7"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

NOTE: I have added the "**ID**" fields by myself. Everything is fine, but there shouldn't be any "members" fields, as they are producing more overhead and make the output worse readable as well as they make the queries more complex.

Comment: I have never seen mongodb doing this. I'd guess SpringBoot or MongoTemplates is adding these fields. You may find a management tool like Robo3T helpful to see what is stored in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a closer look at what the Template does when saving again.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. When writing Json into mongodb, the JsonObject is automatically converted into a BasicDBObject, and during this conversion, MongoTemplate/mongodb (?) seems to modify the objects.
I could solve the problem by doing the conversion JsonObject --> BasicDBObject manually before writing to the database. Works now :)